# Show View in all my app

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I need show a TextView in all Activities, but is much work to do it one by one, because I have +10 Activities.

My objective is when I click in a button, show a textview ("Importing ...") at the bottom of the application. This textview will disappear when I receive a push notification, and I owe a pop up with the response (the pop up also has to appear in any activity).

My project has a custom abstract BaseActivity and all activities extends it.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void setActionBar(@IdRes int idResToolbar) {

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(idResToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    updateFont(toolbar);
}
// ...
}
```

I think I could use for my purpose but not how to do it.

If anyone has any suggestions I will be happy to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Noup, snackbar is not the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) that contains the text view and create a separate class that initializes the PopupWindow on the basis of context given to it.

Now in all your Activities you will have the control of showing and hiding the window as you want. Make sure to make all utility methods required in the separate class to avoid coherence for example hiding and showing the window. setting text of text view of the window and etc.

Comment: But I can position the PopupWindow in any part of the screen? (at bottom)

Comment: Yes definitely you have the control of showing the window using method 

popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, location.left, location.bottom);

Comment: I try show a popupWindow but i receive an error: 
t"oken null is not valid; is your activity running?"

This is the code into a method in my BaseActivity and I call it in my MainActivity:

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ... 

        final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 100, 100);

Answer (score 2):

Use fragments for your content (instead of different activites) you then can add global views to the activity, which holds the fragments.

If you don't want to do that, you'd have to modify the layout(s) in your Base class.

Comment: I have tried to add layout at my BaseActivity, but never shows it, Extending activities overlap, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in onCreate() of your base activity something like

```
setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);
```

And in every other Activity at start of onCreate() method, just use super.onCreate()

And more than that to support different layouts add something like this in onCreate() (example for one of activities)

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_1_layout,rootGroup)
```

where rootGroup is a ViewGroup in your Base Activity, in which you will add additional components for every other activity

Comment: I never use a rootGroup, you can add an example of its use?

Comment: root group parameter in this method is a parameter. Its a viewGroup class or one of its extensions(linearLayout, RelativeLayout etc). So in your xml file of your base activity you should have one of ViewGroup subclasses(cant place the code in the comment, need another post). That viewGroup subclass must have an id. And in your code after you make super.onCreate() - you can find that viewGroup by id - LinearLayout myLinLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLay_id); and then add this minLinLay as a parameter in inflater.inflate method

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, It's been a great help!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a service, which creates a View which can be drawn over other apps (will require the [relevant permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) in the manifest)

You could use one of the open source libraries available like [this](https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead) or refer to [this](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/) example

Answer (score 1):

It's better you use fragments instead of using many activities. However, if you don't wanna do so, I suggest you create a factory which will generate a textview to all activities. Then you must add it into each activity's view.

Comment: create a factory? You can further explain this? Thanks

Comment: A factory is a class you give some parameters and it return to you an object created, for example a `textview` in your case